# error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. The 'ItemGroup' start tag on line 48 position

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget-package-restore, gitlab-ci.yml

I need your help please

I am trying to build a dotnet project on Gitlab-ci using windows runner and I get the error message below

```
C:\\$Path\\SolutionMVC.csproj(176,7): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. The 'ItemGroup' start tag on line 48 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'Reference'. Line 176, position 7.
```

I remain available for any other clarification
Thanx

This is my Gitlab-ci:

```
stages:
  - build

build_only:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8
  stage: build
  tags:
    - runner-windows
    - ltsc2019
  script: 
    - nuget sources Add -Name Artifactory -Source https://${NUGET_PATH} -username ${NUGET_REGISTRY_USER} -password ${NUGET_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
    - '& nuget restore $SOLUTION_PATH'
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" $SOLUTION_PATH -t:Rebuild -p:Configuration=MVC'
```

Answer (score 1):

MSB4025 is an error from MSBuild. MSBuild project files are XML. The error indicates that the XML is not well-formed. There is an `<ItemGroup>` element on line 48 of the 'SolutionMVC.csproj' file that is not being closed.

What does the 'SolutionMVC.csproj' file look like? Is there an obvious typo?

You can run MSBuild on the 'SolutionMVC.csproj' file locally to test for the  MSB4025 error.